# Using VirtualBox/VMWare to deploy software to multi sites?

Tags: virtualization, deployment, virtualbox

I'm currently evaluating the feasibility of using VirtualBox (or VMWare) to deploy the follow project to 10 sites

- Windows XP
- MSSQL 2005 Express Edition with Advanced Services
- JBoss to run 1 in-house software that mostly query master data (customers/products) and feed to other software

Why I want to do this ? Because the IT staffs in my 10 sites are not capable enough and the steps taken to setup those "in-house project" are also complicated

What are the cons I can forsee ?

- Need extra power to run that virtualbox instance
- The IT staffs won't be much knowledgeable 'bout how to install the stuffs
- Cost (license for VirtualBox in commercial environment as well as extra OS license)

I really seek your inputs on the pro/con of this approach, or any links that I can read further

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Being able to standardize a given OS and application stack into a deployable image *does* have a lot of benefits. Creation time is: once + minor changes per site (hostname, ip address).

I'm not sure the cost of the virtualization tool should really be considered as 'high' if you're avoiding putting on extra staff and/or training the ones you have now.

Restoring from snapshots/images is easy, too.

If you find a problem in the image, you can fix it in one place, and re-deploy.

The only issue I see with what I *think* you're asking is that if the images start storing their own data, you can't just re-image. If they're merely talking-back to the 'parent', then I think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should ask you IT Staff, because they won't be really happy to find your virtualized architecture, if they doesn't have enought time, it's maybe cause by all your stuff which parasite her network.

If they're not enought skills, your corporate should maybe fire them, because that kind of stuff is not really difficult to do.

Well, about your question, just done a first image (VDI Disk) with your OS and Softwares and push them to all your clients.

To perform this operation, you will maybe have to build a Deployement server.

About the licenses, you doesn't need one with virtualbox in fact, Corporate licenses are just for those who want to rebuild her own VirtualBox.